# Redux - How to handle multiple actions of the same type at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I have a list of songs, every row has a like functionality. When I click on the like button a `LIKE_SONG` action is being triggered, then a async API request is made and we can receive either a `LIKE_SONG_SUCCESS` action or an `LIKE_SONG_FAILURE` action with an error.

To handle different error/success/loading states I have a `BaseStore` that looks like this:

```js
export type ActionType<T> = {
  type: string,
  payload?: T,
};

export type ActionStore = {
  actions: Array<ActionType<any>>,
  errorActions: Array<ActionType<any>>,
  successActions: Array<ActionType<any>>,
};
```

and I specify start/stop/error action creators that take any action as an argument and store them in the `ActionStore`. So in ALL of my sagas I have something like this:

```js
  yield put(startAction(someAction));
  try {
    // do something
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(errorAction(someAction, error));
  } finally {
    yield put(stopAction(someAction));
  }
```

Next, I've created some custom selectors for picking up the actions that are loading/failed/succeeded e.g

```js
 export const checkLoadingSelector = (
  state: ActionStore,
  actionsToCheck: Array<string>
 ): boolean => {
  const { actions } = state;
  return actions.some((action) => {
    return actionsToCheck.includes(action.type);
   });
 };
```

Which I'm using later in some component containers like this:

```js
const mapStateToProps = ({ actionStore }) => {
  return {
    isSongLikeLoading: checkLoadingSelector(actionStore, [songActions.LIKE_SONG]),
  };
};
```

This is working fine for most of the time. The **PROBLEM** starts if there are multiple actions with the same name. Let's say I click quickly on 5 different song like buttons and trigger 5 `LIKE_SONG` actions. There are now 2 problems:

1. The `isSongLikeLoading` from the mapStateToProps will be set to `TRUE` until the last of those 5 requests finishes which is not good.
2. When the first `LIKE_SONG` actions completes the `stopAction(someAction)` is being triggered which removes a `LIKE_SONG` action from the `ActionStore` actions array. The problem again is that `LIKE_SONG` is not unique and at that time we have 5 `LIKE_SONG` actions thus we can remove the wrong one which will produce wrong UI state.

I don't want a working code solution for this problem, that's not what I'm searching for. I want to start a discussion on how to properly design my stores/actions to easily handle (and distinguish) multiple actions of the same type that have been triggered at the same time to provide a good user experience in my app. Most of the articles I read tackle really simple situation which do not have multiple actions of the same type at the same time thus I don't know if I'm doing something completely wrong and this issue does not exist in other projects or what's the case

My current idea for solving this issue is to add a unique id to those actions.

```js
export type ActionType<T> = {
  id: string // unique id generated probably using uuid() method
  type: string,
  payload?: T,
};
```

There are however two problems with this approach:

1. Not sure if this `id` field is a valid field, going through the Redux docs I see that the actions should have `{type, payload, meta, error}` fields only
2. The check `checkLoadingSelector` would not be so convinient to use anymore. The user instead of the `type` would need to insert a unique action `id` which first he would need to get by calling some action like:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
/* currently I return here void, in the solution I have in my mind I would return a string (the unique id of the action), not sure if this is possible however. Then in the component I would store the ongoing ids and base my loading state on those ids rather than on the action type (which is not unique) */
    likeSong: (songId): string => {
      dispatch(likeSongAction(songId));
    },
  };
};
```

Would this be a good way? Do you have some thoughts about it?

Comment: You must be calling an API something like: `/songs/123/like` (123: songId) and `/songs/123/dislike` via  async action creators like `likeSong(123)` and `dislikeSong(123)`. Now, you only need to find out the `songId` when `LIKE_SUCCESS` (and similar) action was received in the reducer. (This should be easy using URL or meta like you already found about that.) After you are able to find `songId` in the reducer, you can do something different for each `songId`, hence, the ACTIONS can be handled differently.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`batch`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/batch):

```js
import { batch } from 'react-redux'

function myThunk() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    // should only result in one combined re-render, not two
    batch(() => {
      dispatch(increment())
      dispatch(increment())
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your demand is pretty proper for redux-saga actually. I think there are 4 solutions to fix that.

1. Firstly you can just take the last request using with "takeLatest". (https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api#takelatestpattern-saga-args)
2. Secondly you can use "takeLeading the trigger action for leading request. (https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api#takeleadingpattern-saga-args)
3. Third, you can fork all requests and wait for all of them to complete. Fork (https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api#forkfn-args)
4. And Latest, (this is the option I recommend) using "spawn" you can start completely independent requests from saga tree. (https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api#spawnfn-args)